# How can I compare the effect of an pre-post intervention between two groups with multiple numeric dependent variables?

Tags: anova, statistical-significance, repeated-measures, biostatistics, group-differences

I have collected data from two groups (age 25-30, age 30+). In each group I have 10 patients. I performed  several medical tests (i.e., R.B.C, Liver test, etc.) on the patients, before and after treatment.

The data look like this:

```
Group 1
                    Test1           ...          Test 10   
               Before    After                  Before    After

patient 1       10        16                     13  
patient 2       12        11                     19
```

It's the same for  Group 2.

#### Question

How can I test the effect of the treatment in both groups?

Comment: See also this question on best practice for examining differences between groups in a pre-post design: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Comment: Can't you simply do a mutliway ANOVA?

Comment: @Michael: I thought that multiway ANOVA will work perfectly if there are not dependent variables (i.e., Before and After). Do multiway ANOVA consider the dependent variables?

Comment: Aren't the groups what form the dependent variable?  Regression, analysis of variance and analysis of covariance all fall under the category of the general linear model.  You can formulate your problem as a general linear model.  I think maybe you meant that you have independent or predictor variables.  If that is the case analysis of covariance is possible.